# Copy existing table in the middle of a document

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to copy a table after an element that I previously select. but I can't, error message says: **The element must be removed**.

My code:

`DocumentApp.openById(getConfigId());
var body = doc.getBody();
var tables = body.getTables();
var copiedTable = tables[3].copy();`

Until this point it's all OK but when I run:

`body.insertTable(2, copiedTable);`

It says: **The element must be removed**.

The error highlights the insertTable line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in order to copy an element and insert it again, you must eliminate it from the tree structure, so, before:

`var tables = body.getTables();
var copiedTable = tables[3].copy();`

You must:

`var lonelyTable = tables[3].removeFromParent();`

And then you can insert it in the tree (the number 2, indicates the element index where you want to insert the copiedTable).

`body.insertTable(2, copiedTable);`

At the end, the complete process would be:

`var tables = body.getTables();
var lonelyTable = tables[3].removeFromParent();
var copiedTable = lonelyTable.copy();
body.insertTable(2, copiedTable);`

I hope it helps.